# Is there a regex or some other method for ascertaining whether or a line from a function in string form is part of a multiline string?

Tags: python, string, static-analysis

I have a function that is stored as a string, e.g.

```
"""def foo():
  print("hello world")
  x = 1
  for i in range(10):
    x += i
    print(x)

  multilinestring = '''hello
world
over
multiple
lines'''
  print(multilinestring)

  secondmultilinestring = '''hello
world
over
multiple
lines
again'''
  print(secondmultilinestring)"""
```

I want to know which lines are part of a multi-line string, by recieving a list of the indices of the lines. For example, in this case, I would want to get the result `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

Is there a regex that can do this, and is able to ignore tripple quote marks that are escaped, for example using backslashes or putting them after comment hashtags? Can it also be made to work for both `"""` and `'''`? Or is there another method, perhaps using linting or another static analysis tool that could work?

Comment: Why at all do you have code within a string ?

Comment: I am making a line profiler as a personal project, and am profiling the lines by storing the function as a string, modifying the string, then exec() it. Please don't judge me.

Comment: Ok, but why not use code and modify the code, btw. forget the existence of `exec`.

Comment: BC i'm making a module and want to have the ability to pass in a reference of the function I'm using, then using `inspect` to get the source code of the function, then automatically modify it to profile it.